# Serializing a UserControl in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I want to Serialize the UserControl in Silverlight. All I want to do is "deep copying". I tried this code which doesn't work:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(UserControl));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(ms, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
Type 'System.Windows.UIElement' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.
```

How can I get rid of this exception?

The obvious question you would want to ask is why would I want to serialize UserControl? The reason, I am trying to use Printing API of Silverlight. I am creating a WriteableBitmap out of my UserControl and then trying to print it. However my UserControl has black theme but while printing it should be white. If I directly modify the "Background" of UserControl it will affect my visual on screen which is not what I want! So I am trying to create a clone of the usercontrol in memory and then modify it's background behind the scenes and create WriteableBitmap out of it and print it. However no luck till now!

Comment: Did you...try following the instructions given in the exception message?

Comment: How can I do that? UIElement are all present in DLLs. How would I mark them Serializable?

Comment: You can mark your class as Serializable, it doesn't have to be the base object.

Comment: I tried that already. It didn't work because UserControl in turn contains various UIElements like Grid etc. To serialize the whole graph it would mean I would have to extend every single type of object and mark it Serialize which is obviously not feasible.

Comment: have you tried this http://silverlightcontrib.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/49151?projectName=silverlightcontrib#602856

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to have your usercontrol bound to a serializable object.

So instead of serializing a usercontrol which was by design not supported you would serialize your custom object.

This will also result in a cleaner and smaller serialized object.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's impossible. A big part of Silverlight is in native code. A big part of state is in unmanaged memory. Therefore, you won't be able to use any outer serializer to get that state.

The only possible approach is making your printed control be created by templating a view model. If you have a model that keeps the important state of your UI, it will be easy to create clones of controls. Then just style them as necessary.

Comment: I am not able to find XamlWriter. XamlReader is the only one I can find. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, it's not supported. I should've checked.